# Scan for classes in namespaces which arent imported yet

Tags: java, netbeans

Is it possible to make net beans scan for classes in namespaces which i haven't imported YET.

What I mean is, when I begin typing the name of a class, netbeans doesn't show it in its 'code prediction'. it only shows after I have imported the class's namespace.
I want it to show the class in the code prediction regardless of if I've imported the namespace or not

This isn't an issue with eclipse, can I make it work like eclipse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please go through this link.. I have followed this and I achieved what you are trying to get. https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/editor-codereference.html

Moreover, you can always customize your code completion settings to whatever behavior you need. It behaves almost similar to eclipse.